# Gravar dados de um Código de Barras?

Tags: android

Estou tentando desenvolver um app para leitura de arquivamento de CT-e para isso preciso gravar os dados lidos no código de barras, estou usando a biblioteca ZXing ,mas quem recebe é um `textview` .

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE:
                IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode,
                        resultCode, data);
                if (scanResult == null) {
                    return;
                }
                final String result = scanResult.getContents();
                if (result != null) {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                           txtScanResult.setText(result);

                        }
                    });
                }
                break;
            default:
```

Como fazer que um `EditText` receba e grave os dados?

Agradeço antecipadamente a ajuda.

Comment: Você sabe como gravar os dados? Será gravado nas SharedPreferences , ou no sqlite? Dê mais detalhes sobre o que vc possui, e o que quer fazer, para que nos facilite ajudar! Saudações!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia! 
É interessante que que realize uma pergunta para cada dúvida: 
Para que receba e exiba em um EditText, segue o trecho:

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            /* este é seu código! */
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            /*Aqui seu EditText recebe o código*/
            txtScanResult.setText(contents);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Boa noite , esclarecendo a pergunta: eu já recebo os dados em um TextView o que quero é que seja passado ou recebido por um EditText para assim grava-lo em um BD.